# Is $X\times Y$ isomorphic to $Y\times X$?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category with finite products. Let $X,Y$ be objects of $\mathscr{C}$. Is it true in general that $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$ are isomorphic objects?

Comment: Can you prove that $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @HalCanary in some concrete categories yes, for example for sets or groups

Comment: Yes. They represent the same functor, so you can use the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: (The Yoneda lemma lets you say "$(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$" in full generality by interpreting $x, y$ to be generalized points (morphisms from a third object $Z$) and interpreting $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ as a natural transformation. So Hal's argument can be salvaged in general.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Given product diagrams
$$X \xleftarrow{p_1} X \times Y \xrightarrow{p_2} Y \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y \xleftarrow{q_1} Y \times X \xrightarrow{q_2} X$$
We obtain an isomorphism $\langle q_2, q_1 \rangle : Y \times X \to X \times Y$, with inverse $\langle p_2, p_1 \rangle$. Then, in fact,
$$X \xleftarrow{q_2} Y \times X \xrightarrow{q_1} Y$$
is a product diagram.

---

Remember, product diagrams — like anything defined by a universal property — are only defined up to isomorphism. $X \times Y$ is just a name we give to a particular choice of product of $X$ and $Y$ (usually with some implicit choice of projection morphisms), but there may be others. The above shows that $Y \times X$ is also a product diagram for the pair $X,Y$ (as well as the pair $Y,X$).

For example, in $\mathbf{Set}$, if $f : Z \to X \times Y$ is *any* bijection at all then
$$X \xleftarrow{\pi_1 \circ f} Z \xrightarrow{\pi_2 \circ f} Y$$
is a product diagram, where $X \times Y$ denotes the Cartesian product and $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are the usual projection maps. So for example any $6$-element set is a product of the sets $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1,2\}$ (but usually with different projection maps).